# Background color on block of text on top of image

Tags: html, css, background, background-color

I'm trying to display a block of text on top of image in such a way that it displays only on hovering on the image. The text is displaying as I want but, the background applied to the div  is not.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HZqyA/1/

Hovering over the image displays the word stars but, I want it to display with white background underneath the word 'stars'. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

CSS from jsfiddle pasted below. Having trouble pasting html

```
CSS: 
.pu {
    display:block;
    width:185px;
}

.add_rating {
  min-width: 140px;
  display: inline-block;
   background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
}

.pu .add_rating {
    display: none;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    background:  rgb(255,255,255);!important;
    background-color:  rgb(255,255,255);!important;
    background-image:  rgb(255,255,255);!important;
    min-height: 22px;
}

.pu:hover .add_rating {
  display: block;
     background:  rgb(255,255,255);!important;
    background-color:  rgb(255,255,255);!important;
    background-image:  rgb(255,255,255);!important;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: Just add `position: relative` to `.addRating` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a position property other than the default, `static` so that you can create a new [stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#z-index) and so that `z-index` will apply. Adding `position: relative;` to `.pu:hover .add_rating` will enable you to put the background of `.add_rating` on top of the image.

```
.pu:hover .add_rating {
display: block;
background:  rgb(255,255,255);
position: relative;
z-index: 1000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HZqyA/3/

Answer (score 2):

Would you mind if I cleaned some junky CSS in your fiddle? Take a look

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/HZqyA/4/)

```
.pu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.pu:hover .add_rating {
    display: block;
    color: #f00;
}

.add_rating {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

> Note: You are using `!important` which you should ignore it unless
>   required, I've cropped down your CSS drastically

Answer (score 1):

Use position:absolute to `.add_rating` and `position:relative` to parent div

Your CSS is pretty long and that is not really required so compress it like this

```
.pu {
    display:block;
    width:185px;
    position:relative
}

.add_rating {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0; left:0;
  min-width: 140px;
   background: rgb(255,255,255);
    color: #f00;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 22px;
}

.pu:hover .add_rating {
      display: block;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HZqyA/2/)**